# How do I remove "on PrintServerName" from printer name when deployed?

Tags: printer, print-server, shared-printers

We are publishing shared printers from a print server with GPP (Win Server 2012 R2), and all is good and well. But is it possible to have the shared printers added to the clients without the *"on PrintServerName"* in their names?

For example a TCP/IP printer is added as *"Printer1"* while a shared printer from the print server is added as *"Printer1 on PrintServerName"*

We have our reasons for using a printserver but it looks cleaner without the servername added to the printers name on the client.

We're using a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Thanks!